# Проблема с Multipart (Servlet + MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Я написал проект который должен выводить на странице всех студентов в виде таблицы фио студента и рядом должна быть его добавленная аватарка.

Так вот я прописал конфигурацию, но с контроллером проблема.

WEBMVCConfig

```
package fallen.java.schoolmaven.config;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;


import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "fallen.java.schoolmaven")
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean

    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
                InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css");
    }

        @Bean
        public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
                return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
 }
}
```

ServletInitialazer

```
package fallen.java.schoolmaven.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { HibernateConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

        @Override
        protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("", 2097152, 4193304, 2097152));    
    }
}
```

Можете помочь как правильно написать в контроллере Addstudent чтобы вместе c фио добавлялась фото и хранилось в БД

```
package fallen.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import fallen.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import  fallen.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;

@Controller
public class StudentController {
    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView hello(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }

    // Get All Users
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveNewStudent(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");


        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }
        boolean isAdded = studentService.saveStudent(student);
        if (isAdded) {
            mv.addObject("message", "New student successfully added");
        } else {
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEditedUser(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(result.toString());
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }
        boolean isSaved = studentService.saveStudent(student);
        if (!isSaved) {

            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }

        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        boolean isDeleted = studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        System.out.println("Удаление студента: " + isDeleted);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");
        return mv;

    }

}
```

Student

```
package fallen.java.schoolmaven.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private MultipartFile avatar;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

     public MultipartFile getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }
    public void setAvatar(MultipartFile avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + ", avatar=" + avatar + "]";
    }

}
```

Вот моя БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте `byte[]` вместо `MultipartFile` для поля `avatar`. Hibernate не знает как хранить `MultipartFile`.

Comment: А зачем вам сохранять multipart в базу? сохраняйте файлы на сервере в какую-то отдельную папку, а в базу уже сохраняйте путь к ней.